# How to create a function in php which works with a textarea to print the text with the equivalent color by entering something like [color:red]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

How can I create a function in PHP, which works with a `textarea` to print the text with the equivalent color by entering something like `[color:red]`??

This function actually works similar to facebook's `@[profile_id:0]` stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this client Side: Use JS and parse the textarea's content to find the BB Code like [color:red], then apply something like

```
document.getElementById("yourTextArea").style.color = "red";
```

If you want it server side so that users enter the BB Code, click on the submit button and the text is highlighted in the selected color, then you need to write a php function that will parse the textarea's content. Use [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) here to look for your BB code.